# What is this fingerprint bar on my phone?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I've had this phone for a few months now.  During normal usage today, this thing suddenly appeared.  Tapping, long-pressing, swiping did nothing.  It persisted above everything, even the keyboard (as seen), until I rebooted.  Checking the running apps didn't show anything weird.

Anyone have any idea what it is or where it came from?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what it is, but I also just had it pop up an hour ago. As you said, persistent between apps and screens, but goes away on landscape orientation. I am on a Moto X Dev running Eclipse 4.4.2.

Edit: It seems to be a feature added by the latest update from LastPass:
http://blog.lastpass.com/2014/04/lastpass-adds-biometric-security-on.html

Edit 2:I have just been stopping the floating fingerprint overlay service when it appears for now until last pass fixes the issue.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yup, so the IOS version just was updated for fingerprinting and some genius at last pass must have used the code on the android version as well. Giving us this awful useless gray brick. Brutal

The second i deleted last pass, which i really cant do permantely or I would be screwed. the box went away.